# How to detect rapid .change() events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;    
    $('.coInput').on('change', function () {
        var itemID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var rate = $(this).val();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('disabled', true);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/update_crackout/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'object': itemID,
                    'rate': rate
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#weight-'+itemID).html(data.weight);
                    $('#price-'+itemID).html(data.price);
                    $this.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            })
        }, 500)
    })
});
```

It doesn't seem to work consistently. It is pointed at a number field. When I use the up/down arrows to change the value, it works the first time, then only intermittently after that. What causes .change() to miss some of my changes?

I tried removing everything except for a single `console.log()` and it did the same thing.

Comment: Update to this: I've discovered that `.change()` doesn't fire until the mouse leaves the box. Simply clicking the arrow doesn't trigger the function. Maybe I am looking for something else?

Comment: _"What causes .change() to miss some of my changes?"_ `setTimeout()`?

Comment: what do you mean by `it misses`

Comment: I think I identified the problem, see my comment above

Comment: Use `keyup keydown input` along `change`

Comment: That is the answer! Thanks Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. **Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value**.
>
> <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

So, if you need the event to be fired with every change, use "input" event.

Here's a codepen to show it working: https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/BJPYoY

```js
$("input").on("input", function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="" id="">
```